# Protecting your Connection String on Shared Hosting

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption, asp.net-mvc-5, web-config

I am creating a website using MVC5 & EF6.  I am also using a shared hosting to publish this website.  Now the problem that I have is that my connection string at the moment is sitting in plain text in the web.config file.  I am having a very hard time finding a "direct" answer on how I should deal with this.

I have come upon many articles such as [this one](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/1057632/programmatically-encrypt-the-connection-string-in).  The article shows me how to encrypt the Connection Section of my web.config.  So I tried following its example and encrypted the mail section it shows in that example.  After I ran my code I noticed that my entire web.config file changed.

It use to be like this:

```
<system.net>
  <mailSettings>
    <smtp from="info@Site.com">
      <network
        host="mail.Site.com"
        port="25"
        userName="info@site.com"
        password="password" />
    </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

and now it is like this:

```
<mailSettings>
  <smtp configProtectionProvider="RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider">
    <EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
      <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc" />
      <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <EncryptedKey xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
          <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5" />
          <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <KeyName>Rsa Key</KeyName>
          </KeyInfo>
          <CipherData>
            <CipherValue>odapFFPDF1Fgsk2wyvbwVC4SNISqhWc9lXiAq+I/OW3wVVqBCPowxyen9M7c9+KUBkXmGSfaUVxDMlqutChv6g6VU8h4TWG3W6Tw/istjfw/UYrRsGguPiOqdvRsl9XLBmnS37v99+VX7FEA9TKb6ufC0a3Defp2MNpGTvTIR20=</CipherValue>
          </CipherData>
        </EncryptedKey>
      </KeyInfo>
      <CipherData>
        <CipherValue>lHPPFRJAH2hIm/Ya+ABRMP5mo5rEYwL2aBJQ/DT4Q+1OZXaftutiddxxJZ4LSgw3pzi1QJpU8eOPwFVebvqFVA4cjs27l8Iqz50E/R/tBfS7e2oqdWTRsc8IFfE/xOIieMp22BuFsYEDbgnIbLdbHJnw+92zyt2lUlzJpW9epNpnb29sVQhtNJ9cPjAaYAaU</CipherValue>
      </CipherData>
    </EncryptedData>
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

My only problem right now is how do I read those values inside my code without having to decrypt and save the config file.  I do not want to rewrite the webconfig file ever time I need to read the mail setting section or even the connection string section.

If I have a method like this:

```
public static string DecryptMailSettings()
{
    var config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
    ConfigurationSection section = config.GetSection("system.net/mailSettings/smtp");
    if (section.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
    {
        section.SectionInformation.UnprotectSection();
        return section.???;
    }
    return "Nothing was read";
}
```

How do I get the value of lets say "host" from the example above.

Comment: You have chosen to Encrypt your entire mail settings. Seems like you only want to encrypt the username and password.
If you cant untangle the Host name from the Encryption, maybe you should add a simple app settings Key Value with your host name

Comment: @DaniDev I am asking how do I untangle hostname from the encryption.

Comment: What I am suggesting is that if the encryption/decryption is working fine  and it seems like that 'untangling' host name is troublesome then just add a value to your <appsettings>. 

LiKE THIS:
<appSettings>
    <add key="MAILHOST" value="mail.Site.com" />

, and then read that in your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation:

*ASP.NET automatically decrypts the contents of the Web.config file when it processes the file. Therefore, no additional steps are required to decrypt the encrypted configuration settings for use by other ASP.NET features or to access the values in your code.*

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtkwfdky.aspx

Comment: so in other words, I could encrypt the entire config file if I wanted to upon startup and every time the website attempts to read a value from it, it will decrypt it first all on its own without me having to add any extra logic?

Comment: You should encrypt it before deployment. Follow the instructions in the documentation.

Comment: It is shared hosting, therefore I cannot run aspnet_regiis.  For this reason, I am looking to do this at runtime with the code.  With that said, I still need to be able to read the value for hostname lets say so that I can configure my Email Service.  How would I read that key?  According to that article, to read the value I still need to decrypt it first.

Comment: I have hosted plenty of websites without encrypting the web.config and have never run into any security issues. This is because the file sits behind all the protection provided by your hosting service. I personally wouldn't concern myself too much with this.

Comment: If you still insist on encrypting the file, as the article mentions, ASP.NET will automatically decrypt it so you don't need to do anything. Anytime the file changes ASP.NET senses it and will reload it anyways so you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am suggesting that if the encryption/decryption is working fine, and it seems like that 'untangling' the Host Name is troublesome then just add a value to your web.config .

Like This: 
    `<appSettings> 
    <add key="MAILHOST" value="mail.Site.com" />` , 
and then read that in your code.

Ex:

```
string HostName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MAILHOST"].ToString();
```

Comment: host name was a random value I chose, what if I want to look at the password?

Comment: I cant imagine a good reason to look at or 'read' the password in the code. If you want to just unencrypt the encrypted file then you can follow the decryption instructions:
 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy.aspx

Comment: Decryption examples provided here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.protectedconfigurationprovider.aspx

Comment: Again, this is shared hosting, I cannot run aspnet_regiis.  Your second example shows how to unprotect and protect, it doesn't show how to read the value after unprotecting.  In my question I already linked the article that shows how to do what your second link does, my question was how do I actually read the value after I unprotect it. I do not want it to rewrite and resave the config file when I want to access the data.

Comment: I believe I understood. What I am saying/asking is: why would you want to access the data in your code once it was encrypted, presuming that you had the correct values in there and it was connecting to your mail server correctly? 
If you want to test the connection values, then do that with the web config unencrypted and then encrypt it once you have the settings correctly. you can save an unecrypted  version of the config file in your development environment for reference. This is to save you the trouble of bulding an uncryption procedure into your live website

Comment: If you really need to know, it is because of Integration Testing with Detailed Logging, This will not be stored on the server until I wish to run it.  Call it something goes very wrong and I need to debug, I'd rather not do that on the live site, but instead, run my integration test to see what failed and where.  As things fail I want to log everything about the failing procedure, including the encrypted values.  I may not be logging the password directly, but I will be logging other things.  I have not provided a full list of values that will sit in the web.config that I wish to encrypt.

Comment: This is there for those moments when your logging is just not enough and tracing just spits out too much crap for you to go through in a timely manner.  The way I have my code designed allows me to write tests in such a way to test exactly the functionalities I want to a specific method if I choose to.  In any case, I feel this is getting off topic, all I was really hoping to find out is how to read that value once I decrypt it as I have shown in my question.

Comment: I Understand. Normally though, ASP.net Encryption, only encrypts sensitive connection strings or Parameters which you would NOT want to read/log etc. 
So my suggestion/answer is  was based on your specific example where you were encrypting the <mailSettings> . in which case the relevant information that you wanted to retain was hostname. if you want to encrypt other sections (not sure why you would want to do that) then maybe pass the relevant debug info in another <appsetting> key value pair.